# Alarm Manager doesn't trigger if the app is closed (Removed from recent applications)

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have written the code that will send notification on a specific time even the app is closed. This code works fine for me but there is just only one problem that I'm not able to understand.

**Failing Scenario:**

When I install the application and set the alarm from the interface and close the application(remove the application from recent applications), my broadcast receiver doesn't get trigger.

**Working Scenario:**

When I install the app and it opens first time, I close it and open the application again. After that I set the alarm and close the application again. This time I broadcast receiver gets trigger.

I don't know why it doesn't work the same way when I open the application first time after installation.

**Time Picker Dialog to Set Alarm**

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int pickerHour,
                              int pickerMinute) {
            Calendar Cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = pickerHour;
            int minute = pickerMinute;

            Cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            Cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            Cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            Editor e = sharedPrefs.edit();
            e.putLong("userTime", Cal.getTimeInMillis());
            e.commit();
            mytime.setSummary(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getBaseContext())
                    .format(new Date(Cal.getTimeInMillis())));

            new AlarmTask(UserSettingActivity.this, Cal).run();
        }
    };
```

**Here is my alarm manager class code**

```
 public class  AlarmTask implements Runnable{

    private final Calendar date;
    private final AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private final Context context;

    public AlarmTask(Context context, Calendar date) {
        this.context = context;
        this.alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        Log.d("abc","alarm settled");

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, com.quotes.beinspiration.AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 5399, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Broadcast Receiver Code**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("abc","Broadcast Received");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

**Broadcast Registered in Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name="com.quotes.beinspiration.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve it? I am facing similar problem. Help me if you can.

Comment: Did you install the app by running from Android Studio or manually/Play Store?

Comment: Yes i solved it bro

Comment: How do you solve it brother? Please give your solution to this link. Thanks in advance.